# Have large pixels on java graphics

Tags: java

I am somewhat new to java, and I'm trying to make a game that has large "pixels" that are actually 5*5 pixels large. I have tried to turn the graphics into an image and then resize the image, but it always returns a huge amount of errors. I am implementing ActionListener and using timer to create a game loop, if that means anything important.

I have the variable screen set as a createVolatileImage(160, 160);

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    timer.start();

    Graphics draw = screen.getGraphics();
    draw.setColor(new Color(50, 100, 50));
    draw.fillRect(0,  0,  100, 100);

    draw.setColor(Color.black);
    draw.drawString("Text",10,10);

    draw = getGraphics();
    draw.drawImage(screen, 0, 0, 800, 800, 0, 0, 160, 160, null);

    draw.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Are you getting compiler errors or runtime errors?

Comment: I think that they are runtime errors.

Comment: What's the *first* error that shows up?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: OK, that's a runtime error.  It should have a stack trace that tells you which line it's coming from, which goes a long way towards figuring out why it's happening.

Comment: The error is right at Graphics draw = screen.getGraphics();

Comment: If you're getting a `NullPointerException` on that line, I'm going to assume that `screen` is null.